# Single day trip from Munich to Liechtenstein

Tags: germany, munich, liechtenstein

I am planning for a 1 day trip to Liechtenstein. I have found a way to get there by first going to Lindau and then to Schaan or Vaduz. Now my questions:

1) Is there any cheaper and time saving route to get there?
2) I am planning to return in the evening. Or are there more places to see and hence requires more time to spend?
3) Is there any sort of cheap city card which gives me access to the tourist places and public transport?

I did my research on this trip but some posts in the internet are too old or do not have proper information. Would really appreciate someone helping me sketch this plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, you have three question in one here. I try to answer all of them.

1) It depends how you want to come to Liechtenstein. Basically, there are two options: by car or by train.

To get to Liechtenstein by car, you would leave Munich on the A96, travel trough Memmingen to the German border town Lindau. Then you cross into Austria, but leave Austria again at Hohenems to cross into Switzerland. In Buchs or Sevelen, you leave the Swiss highway and cross over the Rhine into Liechtenstein. Be careful, for both the Swiss and the Austrian highways you need toll stickers. The shortest period is 10 days in Austria and 1 year in Switzerland. The whole journey will take around 3 hours (depending on traffic and where exactly in Munich you start).

If you decide to take the train, you should look for the connections to Buchs SG (Switzerland) or Feldkirch (Austria) since Liechtenstein has no real train station. From both towns, it's only a short bus ride to Liechtenstein and the buses leave at least every half an hour. For example, you could take the connection that take 3:57. For this, in Munich, you take the train towards Zurich HB and get of in St. Magrethen (Switzerland). From there, take the train towards Chur (Switzerland) and get off in Buchs SG. From there, it's a 5 to 10 minutes bus ride into Liechtenstein. Checkout www.ssb.ch for train schedules (also covers Liechtenstein buses) and www.liemobil.li. Be careful: in the evening the connection might be scarce and take way longer.

There are also daily buses going from Munich to Zurich (http://meinfernbus.de/). Maybe taking such a bus to Zurich and then the train to Sargans or Buchs SG is also an option.

You might also want to check out this [site](http://www.tourismus.li/en/our-country/arrival-and-transport.html) that summarizes alternatives to travel to Liechtenstein.

2) It depends what you want to do. Liechtenstein is particularly famous for its mountain areas. So if you want to go hiking or skiing, one day is probably a little bit tight, but definitively doable. Other than that, you can visit the pedestrian area in Vaduz, the art museum and the castle in Vaduz and probably just cruise through the whole country to get a glimpse. Also try to go up to Triesenberg and/or Malbun to get a view about the Rhine valley. For this, a day is more then enough.

3) I'm not sure if such a card exist. But there is a tourist office right in the center of Vaduz (opposite of the post office). Probably you could go there and just ask. There is a bus ticket for 24h [available](http://www.liemobil.li/content.aspx?auswahl=5975&mid=5975).

Comment: It does not necessarily make sense to drive through Switzerland when going from Munich to Lichtenstein if you need to purchase the 40 CHF toll sticker just for one trip. Following the Austrian motorway A14 to Feldkirch and entering Lichtenstein from the Austrian side without transiting Switzerland at all is actually a bit shorter (distance) and should not take more than a few minutes longer. If you have another 30 minutes to spare, you can even avoid the Austrian motorway and avoid paying toll at all.

Comment: That's true. It depends on which kind of toll stickers you already have. Unfortunately, the corridor toll sticker for the Austrian highway between Bregenz and Hohenems ist not available any more.

Comment: And if you are *renting* a car, one can inquire which toll stickers it has already. No reason to buy Mr Sixt or Mr Hertz that sort of gift.

Answer (score 4):

A day is probably good for Liechtenstein, unless you ski. However, the nearby Feldkirch (in Austria) is a wonderful base to explore some countryside Austria, and there are numerous buses as well as some trains that map out of Feldkirch, and you can drop in at different places, have a walk, catch another bus/train, etc. Dornbirn and Rankweil (with its very impressive church) are two notable areas in the neighbourhood of Feldkirch.

As for Liechtenstein itself, do not miss the view from Triesenberg. I also love the little postal museum at Vaduz, but that's if you are a fan of letters and postal history.

Comment: Odd, I found the postal museum disappointing. I would rate Vaduz of no particular interest at all, other than lunch and mailing postcards with FL stamps.

Comment: Well, the museum is small and could be better, but as a lover of postal history, I didn't mind even what was there. I liked Vaduz, in fact, though it's  just a very simple town. I think I liked it for its simplicity. By the way, I forgot to mention Laterns and Innerlaterns, again very close to Feldkirch and served by public transport: even if one doesn't ski, they are lovely to explore.